# What is the difference between "dual aperture camera" and "dual camera" on a phone?

Tags: aperture, terminology, cameraphones

What is the difference between a "dual aperture camera" and a "dual camera"? As far as I know, a dual aperture camera has two 2 apertures (IR sensor) and 2 cameras.

Comment: I've edited out the bits of your question which were asking for speculation about the future as they're not a good fit for the Q&A format of Stack Exchange - the rest of the question is a good terminology question though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference.

Ostensibly, the phrase "dual-aperture camera" inherently implies that a device has two cameras (typically with different focal lengths) pointing in a single direction, and that it takes simultaneous photographs from both cameras and combines them into a single photo, i.e. it is one camera with two apertures, as opposed to two distinct cameras.

In practice, however, the term "dual camera" is almost invariably used to refer to a dual-aperture camera.  Thus, there is no difference.  It's all just meaningless marketing fluff.

Comment: No longer true. Compare the S9 (non plus!), single camera with electromechanical aperture.

Answer (score 1):

dual apperture means based on the light(luminous intensity) the apperture will switch just like human eyes eg:galaxy s9, if the lux is low,low light situations like night ;it will switch to f1.5 to allow more light to the lens and in bright conditions switch to f2.4 to get vivid,bright photos.if a fixed focus camera,then only narrower area will be captured also miss details in photo so its necessary to switch apperture based on available light.
Dual camera is just 2 cameras one main lens and secondary for depth focus,telephoto,macro,tof,ultrawide eg:galaxy note8(12mp(main)+12mp(telephoto for 2x optical zoom a=n background blur),iphone 7plus)

Answer (score -2):

Found two articles which gives separate details about the two. Hope they would give enough details to get you to differentiate them.

1. [Dual Camera](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-dual-camera-on-a-smartphone-How-does-it-work)
2. [Dual Aperture Camera](http://signup.dual-aperture.com/downloads/Martinello_ICCP2015.pdf)

Comment: While links to supporting information help round out and make answers _better_, what you've done is essentially create a link-only answer (in this case, the rarer _2-link-only_ answer). Please use words of your own to summarize the information found in the links, so that readers don't have to go elsewhere to get the actual answer you're providing. Feel free to judiciously use quotes/blockquotes from the linked sources to support your answer. Please also see: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/175991)

Answer (score -3):

Dual camera is simply one camera on the back so you take normal photos and a front camera to take selfies.

The new Phone cameras are there so you have two distinct cameras, one could have a wider lens and a "telephoto" lens or one camera could be to triangulate the background and add an artificial blur to it, among other possible uses.